# I can't create an object of type MPMoviePlayerController - Unknown type

Tags: ios5, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm trying to create a component to play videos using MPMoviePlayerController. The problem is that it says that its an unknown type. Why is that? I've found tons of tutorials using this.

Here's my code:

```
@interface HIMoviePlayer : UIViewController
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *test;
}

-(void) playVideoWithURL: (NSString *) url;
@end
```

Comment: I forgot to add the MediaPlayer Framework to the Project. 


After i did it works, i used this:

"This can be achieved by selecting the product target entry from the project navigator panel (the top item named movie) and clicking on the Build Phases tab in the main panel. In the Link Binary with Libraries section click on the ‘+’ button, select the MediaPlayer.framework entry from the resulting panel and click on the Add button."

Comment: Still aint working, cause when i try to import a heaer from the mediaplayer frameowkr, it says that cant find it. Any sugestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you import the mediaplayer framework into the header file,

i.e

```
 #import <UIKit/UIkit.h>
 #import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
 @interface HIMoviePlayer : UIViewController
 {
 MPMoviePlayerController *test;
 }

 -(void) playVideoWithURL: (NSString *) url;
 @end
```

I encountered this problem also, but this should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It's totally strange but if you add MPMoviePlayerController to UIView instead of UIViewController it firstly shows error, then if you change superclass to UIViewController, build and change it back to UIView, everything works fine (no errors and MPMoviePlayerController is showing it's content correctly). At least it happened to me, wouldn't mind if someone explains why i occured such behaviour.